# Can Detox automation library automate hybrid and web app?

Tags: mobile, ui-automation, detox

I am exploring Detox automation library by Wix. I tried it on React native and Native app it worked fine. I want to know do this tool have the capability to automate hybrid app and web app? As I don't have any hybrid app and web app source code I couldn't able to evaluate and in google, there is no information about this.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: found it cannot automate web apps. But still needs clarification on hybrid apps. Like the apps which have webview embedded inside a native app.

Answer (score 0):

No, Detox Cannot support Web apps as well as Hybrid apps. It doesn't have any capability to talk to elements displayed inside of Webview. It is developed to support React Native and Pure Native apps.